# Save a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have the variable: `var balance = 50;`
I am wondering if there is a way to save the `balance` variable, so that it maintains its amount when a user enters the webpage again.
What should I do? Can I do it with a `cookie`, do I need to put it in my `MSSQL database`?

And if I can set it with a `cookie` how should i do it than?
Or can it be done with a `jquery/javascript` script, that can save the date.

Comment: You can use session Storage right..?

Comment: Cookie or localStorage should work fine. Did you try to search for a cookie example? Please also search for localStorage examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localStorage.

```js
var balance = localStorage.getItem('balance');

if (balance === null) {
    // Not found, set value from database or wherever you get the value
    balance = 50; // Or whatever value
} else {
    balance = +balance; // Convert the retrieved value to a number, since localStorage stores everything as string.
}

// After manipulating the balance, etc...
newBalance = balance - 20; // Assuming the user just used up 30 credits
localStorage.setItem('balance', newBalance);
```

You have to be careful however, as not to depend on this value from a security standpoint, as the user can modify it.

Comment: Using this, it dosen't set a value?

Comment: How are you using it? Please note that newBalance is not set in the code above, you need to set it. I will edit the answer to make it a bit clearer. But, how are you using the code?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it? What i should do to make it so that the balance in my id="balance" will be replaced with balance = value

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPBejg Here you can see my full code, you can see that when you select a image (i know it is missing) you will get more coins if it hit your selection, and less if it dosent. I'm looking for a way to "save" that balance, so that when a user, closes the browser, and then opens it again, the balance isn't 50, that you start with, but the amount, he left with.

Comment: Updated code, with this solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVjxod

Comment: AMAZING! Thanks alot!

Comment: Is there a way, i can do that every week, if the balance is 0, it will reset too 50? :)

Comment: Yes, there is always a way to achieve anything in JavaScript. You can, for example, save the current date in the localStorage (say the date the user's account hits 0, or the date the user's account was last reset to 50). When the user returns, you can compare the saved date with the current date, and reset the balance if the difference is more than 7 days, and the user's balance is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage`

```
var balance = 50;
localStorage.setItem("balance", balance); // Sets 50 in local storage
localStorage.getItem("balance"); // Returns 50
```

**Limitation** - It will not work if user visits page in other browser/device.

Comment: Ehm how should i do so that the balance it save, is the current balance? Because this, just reset it to 50 :3

Comment: Just set balance again in local storage whenever balance is getting updated.

Comment: This is the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPBejg I'm looking for a way, maybe i asked worng? So that the <b><span id="balance"></span>$</b> Will be the same as when you left :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is the concept of persistence. You can achieve this in a number of ways, but they all rely on saving a little piece of data on the clients computer.

### 1. Use sessions

Most common way to remember a user is to create a session for him on your server. Within this session you can save all kinds of data, for instance a balance. To get this data from your javascript to your session you can send a post request to your server containing the information of the clients balance. The server remembers which user he's handling by the means of a session cookie on the clients computer (contains a unique ID per session).

### 2. Only use cookies

With javascript you can very easily set cookies doing this: `document.cookie = "balance=50"`. Obviously you'll replace the '50' with whatever value the clients balance actually is. Next time the user visits your page, you can read the cookie again using `var cookie = document.cookie`. This works even between browser instances.

### 3. Use a database

If you have the means to identify a user (e.g. he logged in to your website, or by the means of a session) you can just save whatever data you want into a database. Key is to recognize which user you're dealing with.

I like to use sessions when I'm creating a website. I like to keep most of the responsibilities on my server so that I only have to worry about what is displayed on the pages, and not about manipulating data and whatnot. I recommend you using sessions and posting the users balance whenever you want to save it.